# Firebase & Angular: get the tournament with less than 16 subscribers

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and currently working on a website. I want to access my Firebase database, more specifically the tournaments section with 'knockout' subsection. In this subsection I would like to find and return the tournament with a property 'number' of which the value is lower than 16. If there is one then I would like to add a new subscriber to that tournament. If there isn't any, I would like to add a new tournament to the *knockout* section.

All I have at the moment is this code below in my tournaments.service file. I connect to the *knockout* part of the db, but I don't know how to return the tournament with property *number* lower than 16.

(Below, I have also added a screenshot with the structure of the database)[image: Structure of Database]

```
@Injectable()
export class TournamentsService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  getOrCreateTournament(type){
    // type is 'knockout' in this case (like in the database section, see picture)
    let tournamentWithLessThan16 = this.db.list('/tournaments/' + type );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe your function:

```
@Injectable()
export class TournamentsService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  getOrCreateTournament(type){
    // type is 'knockout' in this case (like in the database section, see 
  picture)
     let tournamentWithLessThan16 = this.db.list('/tournaments/' + type).map(items => items.map(item => item));
     tournamentWithLessThan16.subscribe(items => console.log(items));
  }
 }
```